# No matching version found for @aws-amplify/analytics@5.2.9

Tags: npm-install, aws-amplify

I got this issue when I tried to install **aws-amplify**. I tried on a Mac and Windows and I got the same.

```
npm i aws-amplify
```

npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @aws-amplify/analytics@5.2.9.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this github issue, it addresses work arounds for now: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/9934

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).